# How to Normalise Column of Pandas DataFrame as Part of Preprocessing for Machine Learning?

Tags: python, pandas

**Context**

I am currently preprocessing my dataset for `Machine Learning` purposes. Now, I would like to `normalise` all numeric columns. I found a few solutions but none of them really mimics the behaviour I prefer.

My goal is to have normalised a column in the following way with the lowest value being converted to 0 and the highest to 1:

---

**Code**

```markdown
     column                  column_normalised
1    10                      0
2    30            ->        1
2    20                      0.5
```

---

**Question**

- How can I achieve this goal?
- Would you also normalise numerically-encoded categorial features or leave them as it?

Comment: This is called min-max normalization and is an established pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy's [`interp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) might answer your first question..

```
df["column_normalised"] = np.interp(x=df["column"],
                                    xp=(df["column"].min(), df["column"].max()),
                                    fp=(0, 1))
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   column  column_normalised
1      10                0.0
2      30                1.0
2      20                0.5
```